# monthNames with glDatePicker

Tags: jquery, localization, datepicker

I can't seem to be able to change the default monthName with glDatePicker. 
Im using this:

```
 $('#mydate').glDatePicker({
            cssName: 'flatwhite',
            monthNames: [ 'ENERO', 'FEBRERO', 'MARZO', 'ABRIL', 'MAYO', 'JUNIO', 'JULIO', 'AGOSTO', 'SEPTIEMBRE', 'OCTUBRE', 'NOVIEMBRE', 'DICIEMBRE' ]
```

});

But I still see the month name in English,
Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: turns out it was an error in an old version of glDatePicker